# Does android/java have a timer class?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to record how long it takes a user to complete my task.

What would be ideal is when a user is ready to start, the timer starts.

When the user finishes, I can stop the timer and see how long the user took.

At the moment I cannot find anything like this (other than countdown which is the wrong way).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is to use the `System` time.Something on these lines....

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis ();
method ();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis ();
long difference = end - start;
```

Comment: Thanks, I should go to sleep, this is embarrassing for me.